# Assigning a value to char* in a struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I have problem with my code i cant assign a string value into char* in a struct. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code and why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct{
char* name;
char* city;
int age;
} person;
void main()
{
person * user;
user = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person*));

cout << "Please fill in the user info.." << endl << "Name: ";
cin >> user->name;
cout << "Age: ";
cin >> user->age;
cout << "City";
cin >> user->city;

cout << "The user info is:" << endl << "Name: " << user->name << endl << "Age: " << user->age << endl << "City: " << user->city << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Choose a language. If it's C, don't use `cin`, and allocate some memory for the strings. If it's C++, use `std::string` and don't use `malloc` or raw pointers. If it's a horrific blend of both, then just give up now.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can't assign a string value". There is only one assignment in that code, which is `user = ...`. (And don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new`.)

Comment: try changing "user = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person*));" to "user = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person)); "

Comment: @molbdnilo Don't use `new` either.

Comment: Sorry, but there is so many things wrong with that code. It is hard to explain what is wrong when the wrongness comes in layers. Yes, it is harsh but sometimes reality is harsh. C and C++ are quite different from typical scripting languages, and require you to have a solid grasp of the memory handling. Get a good C-tutorioal and never touch C++ before you understand pointers and memory management. When you are ready for C++, you should learn how and why to replace `malloc` with `new`/`delete`, Then after you have learned alternatives to `new`/`delete`, you may use c++ in a realworld project.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is a horrible mix of C and C++ style, as Mike's comment says, pick a language and use it properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct person {
  string name;
  string city;
  int age;
};

int main()
{
  person user;

  cout << "Please fill in the user info.." << endl << "Name: ";
  cin >> user.name;
  cout << "Age: ";
  cin >> user.age;
  cout << "City";
  cin >> user.city;

  cout << "The user info is:\n" << "Name: " << user.name << "\nAge: " << user.age << "\nCity: " << user.city << endl;
  system("pause");
}
```

Don't dynamically allocate when you don't need to (then there's no risk of mallocing the wrong amount of memory, and no risk of not mallocing memory for the strings, which are both mistakes you made in your original program).

`main` must return `int` not `void`

`typedef struct {...} x;` is not necessary in C++, just say `struct x {...};`

[Don't overuse `endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged the question with two different languages, and seem to be coding in a ghastly blend of the two. You should choose one language and stick to that.

If this is meant to be C++, then use the standard library:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct person {
    std::string name;
    std::string city;
    int age;
};

int main() {    // not void
    person user;
    // ...
    std::cin >> user.name;
    // ...
}
```

If it's meant to be C, then you need to allocate memory for the strings. Either allocate them from the heap:

```
person user;
user.name = malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE);
user.city = malloc(MAX_CITY_SIZE);
```

or embed them in the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    char city[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int name;
} person;
```

and take care not to overflow these fixed-size buffers when you read from the input.

If you really want to use `malloc` for the structure itself for some reason, then allocate enough for the structure, not just a pointer:

```
user = malloc(sizeof(person));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
malloc(sizeof(person));
```

This would create memory  for holding 2 char* and 1 int.

You also need to allocate memory for char*s in struct which you missed.

Comment: Your original answer was wrong, `malloc(sizeof(person*))` does not allocate space for two pointers and an int. Your edited answer is more accurate, but that's not what the OP's code does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `c++`, but if you choose to stick to `c`, your `user->name` is not allocated memory, neither `user->city`. You need to use `malloc()` with proper size to allocate memory to the pointer variable, then use those to store the values.

Also,

```
user = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person*));
```

should be

```
user = malloc(sizeof(*user));
```

Then , `void main()` should be changed to `int main()` and need to add `return 0`. It's a better practice to send back the exit status to the shell.

---

Note: by seeing the usage of

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

it looks more of a `c++` thing, but IMO, the logic should be same.

Comment: Casting should _not_ be required in most properly written C++

Comment: @JonathanWakely ok sir, updated. please review now. thanks for the input, I mentioned already, i don't know much about `c++`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely by that logic casting should be taken out of the language? I'm pretty sure there is properly written C++ that requires casting at times.

Comment: @AliAlamiri, maybe you missed the word "most" in my comment? Please don't make absurd claims based on the "logic" of something I didn't say. Or maybe you think casting _should_ be required for the OP's simple program, despite there being two answers showing how to do it cleanly in C++ with no casts.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The wording of your comment indicates that properly written C++ shouldn't use casting. The word "most" is just emphasizing the point even more (to me as a reader). But what do I know...

Comment: ‘In case of C++, use `new` and `delete`’ That's not very good advice.

Comment: @ravi, which is irrelevant in the context of this question. Again I never said casting is never needed, I said "Casting should not be required in most properly written C++", why are people even debating that point?

Comment: @AliAlamiri, but that's not what "most" means. It's a qualifier that means "the majority, **but not all**". So that means it is needed in _some_ programs, so your "logic" suggesting it should be taken out of the language is flawed.